# How to create and manage a database cluster in CnosDB?

Tags: cnosdb

I'm trying to use CnosDB to create a database cluster, but I'm not familiar with the setup and management process. I would like to know how to create a new database cluster in CnosDB and how to add or remove nodes. Additionally, I'm interested in understanding how to monitor the cluster's status and performance, as well as how to perform backup and recovery operations. Are there any official documentation or guides available that I can refer to?